# ¿Estructura de datos en java o archivo xml con xpath?

Tags: java, xml, estructuras-de-datos, xpath, patrones-de-diseño

Estoy haciendo un desarrollo, y algunos datos que uso en cuanto a diseño deverian estar representados en un arbol, en concreto son rangos, es decir hay un jefe que tiene a su orden a 5 sargentos que tienen a su orden a 5 cabos etc.

Esto lo tengo representado con un xml.

```
<Grupo>
    <jefe>
        <sargento>
             <cabo>
             <cabo/>
        </sargento>
    </jefe>
</Grupo>
```

En java tengo las clases definidas con los campos del `XML`, la pregunta es que recomendación me daríais, crear un Árbol en java para cargar esta estructura y hacer los cambios consultas etc hay o usar `XPath` para leer datos y guardar datos sobre el archivo `XML` directamente.

Decir que al archivo de `XML` solo va acceder la persona que este usando la aplicación.

Bajo mi opinión pienso que lo mejor seria aprovechar la estructura de datos en árbol que tiene el `XML` y usar `XPath` para realizar consulta o modificaciones etc en vez de cargar todo al software.

Comment: Para mí sería más eficiente guardar el árbol en base de datos que en un archivo xml.  Independientemente porque no utilizas **JXPath** de Apache, que tiene **XPath** y **JAXB** para convertir los datos XML a objetos de datos (DTO/VO).

Comment: Voy a checar las opciones que me planteas, en cuanto a base de datos no lo veo mucho dado que quiero que sea una aplicación en java de hacer click y listo sin mucho jaleo, gracias por tu opinión.